# How to pass data from server to page

Tags: javascript, json

I have web site which in turn has few pages with rich User Experience.

In order to populate JavaScript data, I 'render' text into html page in the following way:

```
<script>
     var _data = [
          new BigDataObject(22022,{}),
          new BigDataObject(30007,
              {
                  "M":new ChildObject(25235,2,296),
                  "D":new ChildObject(25235,1,296),
                  "E":new ChildObject(25235,4,148)
              })
          ];
     ... use _data object in JS functions
</script>
```

Things work well.

But I also need to transfer data from backend via AJAX call-backs preferably using the same 'strings' to pass data. The problem is that I don't know how to properly parse object back.

**Problem #1:** I could transfer strings the same way and parse convert them into objects using eval(), but I heard that 'eval' usage is insecure and should be avoided..

**Problem #2:** I cannot use JSON.parse because the string I've written above is not valid JSON string.

To resolve this I could change the way I generate data and use JSON data instead of imperative instructions.

**Problem #3:** But in this case I will need to make properties of both BigDataObject and ChildObject to be public. Which I would like to avoid.

**Question:** How to implement data transferring so I can hide 'setters' for objects properties and use 'safe' approach

Comment: The constructors of these objects are on the client side?

Comment: Yes, constructors are in the JavaScript as part of whole class definition (if one can apply 'class' to JavaScript functions

Answer (score 1):

I would do a custom object for the response, not using your `BigDataObject` or `ChildObject`.

This way you could generate an response to protect your actual model, but at the same time generate a proper `json` object so you can use `jQuery.parseJSON()` function.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Budda if you think this answer solve your problem think of marking it as accepted. For more info look: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer